# Solve for x when x is on both sides of modular equation

Tags: number-theory, discrete-mathematics, modular-arithmetic

This question is purely out of curiosity.
My little brother got a question for homework to find a rectangle where the Area = Outline.
Both sides must also be integers, obviously.
He found the square 4x4 which was sufficient.
Now, using trial and error where $ y = \frac{2x}{x-2} $ I found that when x = 3 it works.
We get y = 6, x = 3. However I would like all values of y that are integers, so in order to do this shouldnt I solve for x, where 
$ 2x = 0\mod\ (x-2) $ ? And if so, how would I do it?

Answer (score 2):

(You need that $x-2$ divides $2x$, this is $2x \equiv 0 \pmod{x-2}$.)

Since $2x = 2(x-2) + 4$, this simplifies to $4 \equiv 0 \pmod{x-2}$. 
In other words you need $x-2 \mid 4$.

Yielding $x=6$, $x=4$, $x=3$.

Comment: Sorry, that was an accident. My main question, is how would I solve for that?

Comment: Okay. I updated.

Comment: Excellent and simple! should have though of that !

Answer (score 0):

Since the area is $xy$
and the outline is
$2(x+y)$,
$xy = 2(x+y)$
or
$xy-2(x+y) = 0$,
or
$xy-2(x+y)+4 = 4$,
or
$(x-2)(y-2) = 4$.

If $x$ and $y$ are integers,
since $4$ can only be factored as
$2\cdot 2, 1 \cdot 4$,
and
$4\cdot 1$,
the only possible values for
$(x, y)$
are
$(4, 4), (3, 6)$,
and
$(6, 3)$.